# Accessing client's state in a client-server environment

Tags: java, client-server

In a client-server environment, after client connects

```
sock = new Socket(serverName, SERVER_PORT);
fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
toServer = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());

toServer.println(json.toString());
```

I'd like to send a server a bean, which would contain information about client's state.

The only thing that comes to mind is create a bean populate it with data, use Xstream to transform the bean to json format, send json to server and reassemble it on server side.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) should be an easier way to do the same. It will however fairly tightly couple the client and server implementations. This might or might not be a Bad Thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a simpler way would be use to use Java's serialization framework to do all that for you by simply having your object implement [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). You would wrap your sockets outputstream with an [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and simply tell it to write your object. There a lot of gotchas when using [Java's framework](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/serialization/ch11) that you should be aware of, but it's still a good fit for many projects.